# S2D and fault Domain

Tags: sql-server, storage, high-availability, windows-clustering

I am running 2 vm (Windows 2022 datacentre) with 1 OS drive and two drives presented as RAW disks. I created the cluster successfully without storage. When I try the enable StorageSpaceDirect
Enable-ClusterStorageSpacesDirect –CimSession 
I get the following error:

This version of Storage Spaces Direct and fault domains configured as Sites do not support stretch or multisite.

Previously, I was running Windows 2019 Datacentre without any issues.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to create a site. A single site with all of the node would be enough.

```
#Create Site Fault Domains 

New-ClusterFaultDomain –Name Seattle –Type Site –Description “Primary” –Location “Seattle DC” 
New-ClusterFaultDomain –Name Denver –Type Site –Description “Secondary” –Location “Denver DC” 

#Set Fault Domain membership 
Set-ClusterFaultDomain –Name Node1 –Parent Seattle 
Set-ClusterFaultDomain –Name Node2 –Parent Seattle 

Set-ClusterFaultDomain –Name Node3 –Parent Denver 
Set-ClusterFaultDomain –Name Node4 –Parent Denver
```